# Solving Fokker–Planck equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes

Consider the Fokker–Planck equation:
$${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}p(x,t)=-{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}\left[\mu (x,t)p(x,t)\right]+{\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}}\left[D(x,t)p(x,t)\right]}.$$
According to the chain rule, we can write the above equation to the form:
$${\frac {\partial u}{\partial t}}(x,t)+\mu (x,t){\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}}(x,t)+{\tfrac {1}{2}}\sigma ^{2}(x,t){\frac {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}}(x,t)-V(x,t)u(x,t)+f(x,t)=0$$
where $f(x,t)=0)$.  (If I'm not mistaken).

According to the Feynman–Kac Formula, we have the exact solution given below:
$$u(x,t)=E^{Q}\left[\int _{t}^{T}e^{-\int _{t}^{r}V(X_{\tau },\tau )\,d\tau }f(X_{r},r)dr+e^{-\int _{t}^{T}V(X_{\tau },\tau )\,d\tau }\psi (X_{T}){\Bigg |}X_{t}=x\right].$$
Since $f(x,t)=0$, the first term in the conditional expectation vanishes,i.e.:
$$u(x,t)=E^{Q}\left[e^{-\int _{t}^{T}V(X_{\tau },\tau )\,d\tau }\psi (X_{T}){\Bigg |}X_{t}=x\right].$$
What I would like to ask is how this exact solution was obtained.

Can anyone give any clues or reference, much appreciated.

Comment: Not taking into account some notation discrepancies and undefined quantities, you just obtained it yourself. Are you asking for a reference to the proof of the Feynman-Kac formula?

Comment: @IiroUllin Yes, but I didn't find it. From Wikipedia I saw a proof of the correctness of this exact solution, but it wasn't what I wanted. In another hand, the solution to the Feynman-Kac formula might be complicated, but if we knew $f(x,t)=0$, then perhaps the proof would be much simpler.

Comment: OK. I grabbed the following three books on stochastic processes from my shelf, they all have various versions of this result:
Gikhman and Skorokhod, "Introduction to the theory of random processes" (their "Theory" books also have it)
Karlin and Taylor's "A second course in stochastic processes"
Kunita's "Stochastic flows and stochastic differential equations"

There are some less mathematical books such as Risken's "Fokker Planck equation" or Gardiner's "Handbook of stochastic methods" that discuss this kind of things too...

Comment: ...the presence or absence of the $f(x,t)$ term makes little difference -- that's just Duhamel's principle/variation of constants formula. The key part in FK is the $V$-term, which is the extra ingredient on top of Ito formula...

Comment: @IiroUllin Is there any relevant paper that includes this proof?

Comment: That Wiki page that you mentioned has a reference to Mark Kac's original paper, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1990512 ...I think it's been standard textbook material for the last fifty years, so you probably won't find any recent original papers....

Comment: @IiroUllin I see. What really bothers me about the proof in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman–Kac_formula) is how process Y was obtained i.e. $Y(s)=e^{-\int _{t}^{s}V(X_{\tau },\tau )\,d\tau }u(X_{s},s)+\int _{t}^{s}e^{-\int _{t}^{r}V(X_{\tau },\tau )\,d\tau }f(X_{r},r)\,dr$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking. What's wrong with $Y(s)$? The wiki also mentions Bob Kohn's lecture notes where that proof is taken from. Perhaps looking at those notes would help?

Comment: @IiroUllin I mean where does this $Y(s)$ expression come from, How do you know that $Y(s)$ is in this form.

Comment: you just define it like that and the following calculation shows that it works

Comment: @IiroUllin Yeah I know, but this only prove that the $Y(s)$ in this form is a solution to the PDE, I'm just curious why/how do we define $Y(s)$ in this form.

Comment: Well, you define it in this form exactly because this form works for the proof. If you want to understand the intuition behind it, the idea is that $V(x,t)$ may be interpreted as the "killing" rate for the diffusion process at location $x$ and time $t$. $\exp\{-\int_0^t V(X_\tau,\tau)d\tau\}$ is then the "survival" probability. Hope this helps. I am sure any of the textbooks dealing with this formula would have some additional motivation. (I though of another classical source, "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" by Karatzas and Shreve)

Comment: The proof is essentially the same as for the path integral solution of a transition amplitude in QM. You consider a small time and find the solution for such an interval; then you prove that the solutions "convolute", that is, if you have a solution for an interval (t,t′) and (t′,t′′), then you can construct the solution for (t,t′′). In this context that convolution is the Chapman–Kolmogorov equation, but for Markovian processes it is simply an identity on the probability distributions. Section 4.4.2 of Risken's The Fokker-Planck equation sketches the proof (In a different notation).

Comment: Or, by the way, if you know the more-or-less standard proof of the path integral solution of the Schrödinger equation (any modern text on Quantum Mechanics and/or Quantum Field Theory), you can transform the Schrödinger operator into the Fokker-Planck operator and relate the two solutions. It should be possible to put it in the same language that you are writing it.